# Remove apache from ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, package-management

I want to remove apache as if it was never installed, no config files left behind. I intend to reinstall apache2 fresh. I have tried various combinations of apt-get options to no success.

```
apt-get remove apache2
apt-get remove --purge apache2
apt-get purge apache2
apt-get autoremove apache2
```

None of these totally remove apache properly.

Nothing works, the  /etc/apache2 directory still exists. So I deleted it. When I install apache the folder is never created.

Running Ubuntu server 10.10.

Comment: check if apache was really removed by "sudo dpkg -l | grep apache".

Comment: Thanks, had to purge all the apache2 packages before it would uninstall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apache2` does not contain real config files. Try

```
dpkg --purge apache2-common
```

From its description:

```
Apache HTTP Server common files
<...>
This package contains the configuration and support scripts. <...>
```

Comment: To list the files installed with "apache2.2-common", you can use "dpkg -L apache2.2-common". You can find apache configuration files in the list.

Comment: @Khaled: well, is your comment for me or the OP?

Comment: For anyone interested! :)

Answer (score 1):

dpkg --purge apache2

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge $(dpkg -l apache* | grep ii | awk '{print $2}')
```